# how to convert JavaScript code in to sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working on finding the store using sencha touch 2 and i follow this link https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

now i have some Javascript + html files code is shown as below :-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }

   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }

   function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;

     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);
   }

   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations(); 

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }

    function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function parseXml(str) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
      } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
      }
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()"> 
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
    <select id="radiusSelect">
      <option value="25" selected>25mi</option>
      <option value="100">100mi</option>
      <option value="200">200mi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I convert almost all the code is in sencha touch but instead it is not working. here is my code so far

```
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }

   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }

   function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;

     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);
   }

   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations(); 

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }

    function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function parseXml(str) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
      } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
      }
    }

    function doNothing() {}


Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled:true
});
    Ext.application({
        name: 'sencha',
        launch: function(){
            var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,


            items: [{
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Search Stores',

                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name : 'name',
                            label: 'Adress',
                            id: 'addressInput',
                            placeHolder: 'Enter City & State or ZIP code'
                        },
                       {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            label: 'Radius:',
                            options: [
                                {text: '25mi',  value: '25'},
                                {text: '100mi', value: '100'},
                                {text: '200mi',  value: '200'}
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            hidden:true,
                            id:'locationSelect',
                            label: 'Radius:',
                        },
                        {
                              xtype: 'button',
                              text: 'Search',
                              ui: 'confirm',
                              listeners : {
                                  tap : function() {
                                    searchLocations()
                                  }
                              }
                        } 
                    ]
            }]
            });


        }
});
```

so, please let me suggest what i can do ? any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You're really messing up with the code? Why you have put the `html+js` code before the `Ext.Application`?

Comment: @roadRunner only the js code not html, no specific reason behind this, can you please help me

Comment: @roadRunner When I put my JavaScript functions inside the Ext.Application, I got an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

Please get the Maps example working : [Maps Example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example/maps)

from that starting point you should be able to add the functions you require.

you will need to setup your maps using the Sencha-Touch map objects.

Comment: yes i see this link in the documentataion, but instead not able to find the right solution